# Python Removing a sublist in a list without changing the index of other sublists in the list

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array, 2d, indexof

Say for example:

```
list = { [1,2,3],[4,5,6],[3,4],[2,7,8,9] }
```

is there a way in python to remove a sublist and make sure that other sublists index's remain the same. So for example if i was to remove the sublist [3,4], could i make sure that the index of [2,7,8,9] remains as 3 in this case? if this is possible it would really be helpful! thanks!

Comment: Set isn't an ordered data structure, therefore the term `index` is irreverent here. Do you mean 2D list?

Comment: First of all `list = { ... }`  is **not** a list. And you could simply replace the sublist with a `''`empty character or `None`.

Comment: @AhsanulHaque yes 2d list, i want to remove [3,4] in this example without changing the [col][rows] of the other sublists.

Comment: How about deleting the elements in `[3,4]` and keep the empty list like so '[]'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe. It depends on how you use the list and just how "listy" the resulting object needs to be.

```
l = [ [1,2,3],[4,5,6],[3,4],[2,7,8,9] ]
```

You could replace the sublist with something else like a None. Then your code would have to know to ignore None when it processes the list.

```
print(l[3])
l[2] = None
print(l[3])
```

or you could convert the list to a dict and delete the member. You can still index the object but since its now a dict, your code will have to treat it like a dict.

```
l = dict(enumerate(l))
print l[3]
del l[2]
print l[3]
```

These tricks will only work in some specialized environments.

Comment: so if i put none python will know to ignore it and when its brought up it wont be an error? thx for answering btw i appreciate it.

Comment: if i run the 2d list in a loop i get an error, it says object of none type has no length.

Comment: Its not that python knows to ignore it... its that your code could perhaps be written to ignore it. That's where the "maybe" comes from. If your code is processing the lists, it may be sufficient to clear the sublist. To remove all items from a list, you can `del somelist[:]`. Since you have a sublist, `del l[2][:]` is it. Other than that, if you bump into problems you might be able to tweek your code or it may mean this hack isn't going to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can just delete the elements in `[3,4]` and keep the empty sub-list.

```
>>> lst = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[3,4],[2,7,8,9]]
>>> del lst[2][:]
>>> lst
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [], [2, 7, 8, 9]]
```

*Please note that you should not use `list` as a `variable` name as `list` is a [built in function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html)*

Answer (score 0):

But you can store the index with the value as a tuple. First make a modified list which has both index and value. Then you are free to remove any of the element.

```
lst = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[3,4],[2,7,8,9]]
modified = list(enumerate(lst))
```

To explain a bit:

```
modified=[]

for i,v in enumerate(lst):
    modified.append((i,v))

print modified
```

Output:

```
[(0, [1, 2, 3]), (1, [4, 5, 6]), (2, [3, 4]), (3, [2, 7, 8, 9])]
```